# I want to add more than one argument in callbacks. How can i solve this error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, callback, model-fitting, learning-rate

I get this error

> " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_model' "

when I add learning schedule callback `callbacks_list` in model.fit_generator

```
<callbacks=[callback,callbacks_list]>
```

How can i solve this error??

```
lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
callbacks_list = [lrate]
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), #end=75),
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),#start=75),
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),#*25), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),#*75),
                                verbose=2,
                                epochs=300, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback,callbacks_list])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting one of your callbacks in an unnecessary list, which produces the error. Just do this:

```
callbacks=[callback, lrate]
```